# Нахождение суммы максимально близкой к числу

Tags: c++, delphi, pascal

> Представим, что у нас есть `n` чисел. Дано определенное число `k`. Нам
>   необходимо вывести на экран числа, которые в сумме будут давать
>   максимально близкое число к `k` из всех возможных комбинаций.
>
> Например: Даны 4 числа: `8, 6, 3, 1`. Дано число `k: k=13`. Ответом
>   будет являться: `8, 3, 1`, т.к. `8 + 3 + 1 = 12` - это максимально
>   близкое к `13` число из возможных комбинаций.

P.S.: определенных ограничений нет. Это не олимпиадная задача, просто нужно для проекта в школе. `1<n<50`. `1<k<1000`.

Если будет возможность, пожалуйста напишите программу на паскале, но можно и на C++. Мне главное понять алгоритм.

Comment: Стандартная "задача о рюкзаке".

Comment: *Ответом будет являться: 8 3 1, т.к. 8+3+1=12 - это максимально близкое к 13 число из возможных комбинаций* Почему не 8+6=14? тоже отличается всего на единичку...

Comment: Но ведь в задаче о рюкзаке используются два параметра: вес и стоимость.  А здесь я вижу только один параметр. И в задаче о рюкзаке мы пытаемся взять максимум стоимости, главное чтобы вес не превышал максимум. Что мне можно взять за второй параметр?

Comment: 8 и 6 тоже можно взять, но мне хотя бы так решить

Comment: *в задаче о рюкзаке используются два параметра: вес и стоимость.* У Вас вырожденная задача. Все стоимости равны. *8 и 6 тоже можно взять* А вот это бардак - алгоритм выбора должен быть однозначным. Вводите дополнительные критерии. Например, отдайте приоритет бОльшей либо меньшей сумме при равенстве отклонений.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заведите массив длиной K+1  `A:array[0..K] of Integer`, заполните нулями, `A[0] := -1`

Для каждого номинала `C[i]` сканируйте массив c конца. Значение `P` можно составить из `cc=С[i]` и предварительно набранной суммы `pс = P - С[i]`, если соответствующая ячейка `A[pc]` ненулевая. В таком случае запишем в `A[P]` значение `cc`

После нужно проверить массив с конца. Если K-я или предыдущие ячейки ненулевые - соответствующую сумму набрать можно и пройдя к началу, можно выяснить её составляющие

Comment: Что за значение P?
Массив c это я так понимаю массив с заданными числами, да?

Comment: Ячейка массива A[p] соответствует сумме p. C[] - да, массив с заданными числами